# What is the next number in the sequence and why?

Tags: number-sequence, formation-of-numbers

7  4  11  2  14  5  18  3  21  ?

Find the next number in the sequence?

Comment: Hi @mr21, welcome to Puzzling SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already! While we do accept a wide variety of puzzle types, number sequence puzzles such as yours are generally not well received as they often do not have enough information to identify a single most correct answer. See [this meta post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5712/57742) for more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> could be 6 because two sequences nested in one series (and the rule is +4,+3 and -2,+3 alternatingly)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is

> 6, because every second term differs by -2 then +3. 2=4-2, 5=2+3, 3=5-2, so ?=3+3=6.